# sub-menu does not show on the very top bar

Tags: sub-menu

I am using Hestia wordpress theme and i want to create a sub menu on the very top bar, the problem is when i click on it, the link seems to be active but the sub menu does not show. I am working on localhost, any help?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the `Hestia` theme works but normally, you need to create child pages by setting a parent page in your wp-admin `Pages` menu.

Or by going to `Appearances > Menu`, here you can create custom menus and set them to different locations.

Comment: already done that @Nath

Comment: Great, have you tried anything else?

Comment: no i've put the same menu as primary, it works fine, i don't know what to do